# Removing every other element in an array list

Tags: java, arraylist

```
for(int i = 0; i < points.size(); i = i+lines) {
    points.remove(i);
}
```

The idea here is that a user can either remove every other space or every third space or every fourth space .. And so forth, of an array list by entering an `int` "line" that will skip the spaces. However, I realize the list gets smaller each time messing with the skip value. How do I account for this? I'm using the `ArrayList` library from java so don't have the option of just adding a method in the array list class. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You could add the items to remove into a list and then remove the entire list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've [perfomed a benchmark](https://github.com/anjsimmo/javaArrayListBenchmark) of all the answers proposed to this question so far.

For an ArrayList with ~100K elements (each a string), the results are as follows:

```
removeUsingRemoveAll  took 15018 milliseconds (sleepToken)
removeUsingIter       took   216 milliseconds (Arvind Kumar Avinash)
removeFromEnd         took    94 milliseconds (WJS)
```

Removing an element from an ArrayList is an [Θ(n)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list#Linked_lists_vs._dynamic_arrays) operation, as it has to shift all remaining elements in the array to the left (i.e. it's slow!). WJS's suggestion of removing elements from the end of the list first, appears to be the fastest (inplace) method proposed so far.

However, for this problem, I'd highly suggest considering alternative data structures such as a [LinkedList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html), which is designed to make removing (or adding) elements in the middle of the list fast. Another alternative, if you have sufficient memory, is to build up the results in a separate list rather than trying to modify the list inplace:

```
removeUsingIterLinked took    12 milliseconds
removeUsingSecondList took     3 milliseconds (sleepToken with WJS's comment)
```

Comment: Wow! That's a great analysis.

Comment: thanks for the benchmark that really helped with the speed it was awfully slow

Answer (score 3):

Use an Iterator with a counter e.g. the following code will remove every other (i.e. every 2nd) element (starting with index, `0`):

```
Iterator<Point> itr = points.iterator();
int i = 0;
while(itr.hasNext()) {
    itr.next();
    if(i % 2 == 0) {
        itr.remove();
    }
    i++;
}
```

Here, I've used `i` as a counter.

Similarly, you can use the condition, `i % 3 == 0` to remove every 3rd element (starting with index, `0`).

Comment: this works however I can't re-access the new iterator with removed elements. Unless there's a way to reverse the position in the iterator back to the start.

Comment: @magnusreeves To go back to the start, just create a new iterator `itr2 = points.iterator()`

Comment: Thanks, @anjsimmo for editing the answer and answering OP's subsequent query while I was busy answering other questions. Wish you success!

Answer (score 2):

Here is a different approach.  Simply start from the end and remove in reverse.  That way you won't mess up the index synchronization.  To guarantee that removal starts with the second item from the front, ensure you start with the last odd index to begin with. That would be  `list.size()&~1 - 1`.   If size is 10, you will start with 9.  If size is 11 you will start with 9

```
List<Integer> list = IntStream.rangeClosed(1,11)
    .boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());

for(int i = (list.size()&~1)-1; i>=0; i-=2) {
            list.remove(i);
}
System.out.println(list);
```

Prints

```
[1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11]
```

Comment: I perfomed a benchmark, and this answer was the most efficient so far. https://github.com/anjsimmo/javaArrayListBenchmark

Answer (score 1):

You could add them to a new ArrayList and then remove all elements after iterating.

You could set `count` to remove every `count`th element.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Test {

    static ArrayList<String> test = new ArrayList<String>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        test.add("a");
        test.add("b");
        test.add("c");
        test.add("d");
        test.add("e");

        ArrayList<String> toRemove = new ArrayList<String>();
        int count = 2;

        for (int i = 0; i < test.size(); i++) {
            if (i % count == 0) {
                toRemove.add(test.get(i));
            }
        }

        test.removeAll(toRemove);

        System.out.print(test);
    }
}
```

Comment: This works, but is extremely inefficient for large lists, as `removeAll` will need to test every element in `test` against every element of `toRemove`. (e.g. try running it with 1,000,000 elements in `test`).

Comment: If the list has duplicate elements (e.g. two "e"s), this solution will give an unexpected result. If one element is flagged for removal, it will remove all the duplicates of that element as well, regardless of their index!

Comment: Actually, I just did some testing.  For large lists, the `removeAll` method is what is considerably slowing things down.  To allow for deletion of the Nth value I would suggest your if statement to be `(i % count != 0)`.  Then just return `that` list instead of the original.

Comment: @WJS yes, building up a second list and just returning that is much faster than using `removeAll` (was over 5000 times faster in my testing with long lists). The method described in your comment is included as one of the benchmarks in my answer.

Comment: @anjsimmo you are 100% right... at least now I can say I have the best example of what *not* to do... good work!